# Simple channel offset shader in GL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, shader, fragment-shader

Could someone point me in the right direction to creating an effect [similar to this](http://blog.jahfer.com/2012/04/02/experimenting-shaders-openframeworks/) that would run on GL ES 2.0?

.vert

```
uniform vec2 uAberrationOffset; 

void main() {
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

.frag

```
uniform sampler2DRect baseTex; 
uniform vec2 uAberrationOffset; 

void main() {


vec4 coords = gl_TexCoord[0];

// baseTex is FBO of screen (1280x800 -> non-square)
// offset red
vec4 fbo1 = texture2DRect(baseTex, coords.xy - uAberrationOffset);  
// keep green where it is
vec4 fbo2 = texture2DRect(baseTex, coords.xy);  
// offset blue
vec4 fbo3 = texture2DRect(baseTex, coords.xy + uAberrationOffset);  

// FBO channels mixed (incl. offsets)
vec4 colFinal = vec4(fbo1.r, fbo2.g, fbo3.b, 1.);

// Output final pixel color
gl_FragColor = colFinal;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following baby steps will allow you to port these shaders to ES 2.0.

- Do not use old-school uniforms: `gl_ProjectionMatrix` and `gl_ModelViewMatrix`.  Replace these with user-defined uniforms.
- `sampler2DRect` and `texture2DRect` are not supported in ES but you can use a normal `sampler` and `texture2D` call for this effect.
- `gl_MultiTexCoord0` and `gl_Vertex` are old-school attributes.  You'll need to replace them with user-defined vertex attributes.